# Trying to create a carousel with thumbnails in angular but not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, carousel

Following are the template and the consumer of the template. `<gallery>` is the directive I am trying to create.

**TestCarousel.html**

```
<html ng-app="imageCarouselModule" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Carousel</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
    <script src ="imageCarousel.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>

<script>


    var app=angular.module('imageCarouselModule',[]);
    app.controller('MainController',function($scope){

        $scope.images=[{"src":"http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1Kp2JmcnxhBOf66aN_JqMWl3h_okOQKFX_kEqwr9mRe5iPomy"},
            {"src":"http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAoT9UmjmunwFTAA19_n1auOFR_JG017_TUru-E91T7nIH8HyU", },
            {"src":"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfntbVv3pl5wFCe6IdkaMVrme_Au9TD8Z_xE95Ezv6jz8oK4nT", },
            {"src":"http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSAOralDJGSVtfirbHG5VdFqG8fTqXMh7C4Xd_aHCy176SKNQqK", },
            {"src":"http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/122/0/c/landscape_wallpaper_by_nickchoubg-d4yaep3.png", }
        ];

        $scope.action=function(image){
            $scope.selectedImage = image;


        };

    });


    app.directive('gallery',function(){

        return{
            templateUrl:'imgCarousel.html',
            scope:{images:'=',
                action:'&',},

            link:function postLink(scope, element, attrs){
                $scope.selectedImage=$scope.images[0];
            }

        };

    });




</script>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
</body>
<gallery images="images" ></gallery>
</head>
</html>
```

**imgCarousel.html**

```
<div>
<div>
<img ng-src="{{selectedImage.src}}"/>
        </div>
    <ul>
<li ng-repeat="image in images">
<img ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="action(image)">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I am trying to use the event listeners on the directive.

Comment: what events are you listening for in the directive? If you are unsure where to start, the element argument in the directives link function is where you would want to listen for events.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <carousel interval="5000" >
<slide ng-repeat="(key,item) in images" active="selectedImage" ng-swipe-right="prev()" ng-swipe-left="next()">
    <img ng-src="{{item.src}}" >
</slide>
```

Also, may be you can use the animation and touch

```
angular.module("imageCarouselModule", ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTouch']);
```

> Note That, I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4,
>   Angularjs Core 1.4.3 (as slide left and right was not working in the previous version), 
>       Angularjs Animate,
>       AngularJs Touch,
>   and AngularJs UI Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your directive was messed up as well as missing the **restrict** option, heres the fixed version:

```
app.directive('gallery', function() {

         return {
             restrict: 'E',
             templateUrl: 'imgCarousel.html',
             scope: {
                 images: '=',
                 action: '&',
             },

             link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                 scope.selectedImage = scope.images[0];
             }

         };

     });
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
  {{test}}
  <gallery images="images" ></gallery></body>
```